# @Html.CheckBoxFor jquery return data to view

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkboxlist

I have a MVC 5 APP & I am using a @Html.CheckBoxFor I load the View with 1 Dropdown fed by its table (Left Table = 10 items). After a selection is made I want to do a Jquery GET to Controller Action and return Total list of other items available in its table (Right Table = 12 items). Lookup the items selected by Id in a join table (Middle Table = Left & Right Joined). My ajax call works to the GET to the Server and my model gets updated and when I run the Web inspector the values are there but my view is not being updated. Also I I hard code a Id on the initial GET I do get say 12 checkboxes with say 8 checked from my join table as expected. My problem is how to properly return the ajax to the view? Thanks Ahead!

**Model**

```
namespace MPHComplianceTracker.Models
{
    public class CheckBoxListModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }           // Integer value of a checkbox
        public string Name { get; set; }      // String name of a checkbox
                                              //public object Tags { get; set; }    // Object of html tags to be applied to checkbox, e.g.: 'new { tagName = "tagValue" }'
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }  // Boolean value to select a checkbox on the list
    }

    public class CheckkBoxListPostModel
    {
        public string[] SelectedIds { get; set; }
    }

    //Helper class to make posting back selected values easier
    public class CheckBoxListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CheckBoxListModel> Selected { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CheckBoxListModel> Available { get; set; }
        public CheckkBoxListPostModel PostedItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelationshipsVM
    {

        public RelationshipsVM()
        {
            CheckboxList = new CheckBoxListViewModel();
        }



        public CheckBoxListViewModel CheckboxList { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult Relationships(int? id, CheckkBoxListPostModel PostedItems, RelationshipsVM relationshipsVm)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {

                ViewBag.ProtectedResourceKey = new SelectList
                    (db.ProtectedResources.Where(x => x.Active == true), "ListKey", "ListValue");


                return View(relationshipsVm);
            }
            else
            {



                ViewBag.ProtectedResourceKey = new SelectList
                    (db.ProtectedResources.Where(x => x.Active == true), "ListKey", "ListValue");

                relationshipsVm.CheckboxList.Available =
                db.ComplianceRequirements.Where(x => x.Active == true)
                    .Select(x => new CheckBoxListModel
                    {
                        Id = x.ListKey,
                        Name = x.ListValue,
                    });

                //id = 8;

                List<int> complianceRequirementIds = db.MemberComplianceRequirements
                    .Where(x => x.ProtectedResourceID == id)
                    .Select(s => s.ComplianceRequirementID.Value).ToList();


                relationshipsVm.CheckboxList.Selected =
                    db.ComplianceRequirements.Where(x => complianceRequirementIds.Contains(x.ListKey))
                        .Select(s => new CheckBoxListModel()
                        {
                            Id = s.ListKey,
                            Name = s.ListValue,
                            IsSelected = true
                        });

                return View(relationshipsVm);

                //return Json(new { success = true, }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

**Ajax**

```
$("#ProtectedResourceKey").on('change', function () {
    var myData = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Admin/Relationships',
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: myData },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data) {
          //I get the DATA HERE but do not know why it does not show up in the VIEW
                alert("good");

            }
            else {

                alert("bad");

            }

        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="ProtectedResourceKey" class="control-label">Protected Resource:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("ProtectedResourceKey", null, "Select Protected Resource...",                       htmlAttributes:
                   new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ProtectedResourceKey" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProtectedResourceKey)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="checkboxList">
                <style type="text/css">
                    label {
                        display: inline-block !important;
                        padding: 10px !important;
                    }
                </style>

                    @if ((Model.CheckboxList.Available) != null)
                    {

                    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.CheckboxList.PostedItems.SelectedIds,

                                     x => x.CheckboxList.Available,
                                     x => x.Id,
                                     x => x.Name,
                                     x => x.CheckboxList.Selected,
                                     Position.Vertical_RightToLeft)
                    }
            </div>
```